# Can MATPLOTLIB be used from languages other than Python?

Tags: matplotlib

I was wondering if it would be possible to use MATPLOTLIB from a language other than Python.

Scenario:

1. I could have a Windows .NET executable to accept user input
2. do some lengthy calculations.
3. then invoke MATPLOTLIB to display the results

I was comparing with GNUPLOT which is a stand alone executable and you can issue commands to this executable through the command line , thereby making such a scenario possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly.  However, just as you can call gnuplot as a system call, you can also call python to run a script.  And, just as you might create a gnuplot script on-the-fly and then run that through gnuplot, you can also generate a Python script on the fly and run that through python.

It will be harder true interactivity from a program calling python to run a script.  Gnuplot works with pipes and so can better interact with the calling program.  I do not know if that is possible.  You could set up a "python service" and use some inter-process communication (say, XML-RPC or SOAP) to send data between the python process and the calling program.   This can work (I've done it, though not from .NET), but is a bit of work to set up.  Matplotlib is able to work with a GUI event loop, but not with the normal "pyplot" interface, in which `pyplot.show()` tends to block I/O.

In many cases, one can also embed a Python interpreter in an application.  Sadly, with .NET / CLR one would want to use IronPython, which (as far as I know) doesn't work with matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

Not unless there is specific package in the other language (e.g. Julia has the 'pyplot' package) or there is a way of calling python from the other language.

Answer (score 0):

You may compile a python script into an executable. This might be done e.g. using `pyinstaller`. The python code could be rather generic and allow for arguments to be passed to it, which are then used to plot something with matplotlib.
The drawback of this is that the executable would be rather large, because it needs to contain matplotlib and all of its dependencies.